# How to erase polygon with QPainter::drawPolygon() when painting on QPixmap with transparency

Tags: qt

I'm painting onto `QPixmap` with transparency with `QPainter`. How to erase a polygon with `QPainter::drawPolygon()`? I need to erase not only the edges of the polygon but the inside area too.

Comment: A code snippet would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear);
```

See Composition Modes sample provided with Qt.

Comment: How is this related to a polygon, or any shape for that matter?

Comment: @scopchanov He was asking about how to clear the polygon, not how to render one.

Comment: @AlexisWilke, One line of code does not make it clear enough.